# Prove that if $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n$ converges then $f(z) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n z^n$ is continuous at 1.

Tags: complex-analysis

For all $n \in \mathbb N$ let $a_n \in \mathbb C$. Define $f : \mathbb C \to \mathbb C$ as $$f(z) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n z^n$$ for all $z \in \mathbb C$. Assume $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n$ converges. Prove that $$\lim\limits_{z \to 1} f(z) = f(1)$$ such that $\frac{|1 - z|}{1 - |z|}$ is bounded.

I am not sure how to approach this problem, any help is appreciated.

Comment: That's not "continuous at $1$", which would allow $z \to 1$ without restriction.  This is [Abel's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%27s_theorem) on power series.

Comment: Note that you can't define $f(z)$ unless you tell us something about the $a_n$ first. And the later assumption that $\sum a_n$ converges is still not enough to define $f(z)$ for all $z.$

Answer (score -1):

This is not true. Take $a_n=1/n^2$ and WLOG, assume $f(1)=0$ (by subtracting a constant). If $f$ were continuous at 1, then for any $\epsilon>0$, we could find a $\delta>0$ such that whenever $|z-1|<\delta$, $|f(z)|<\epsilon$. But then notice that 
$$
\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{(1+\delta/2)^n}{n^2}=\infty
$$
and so we cannot possibly have $|f(1+\delta/2)|<\epsilon$.

Comment: If $a_n=1/n^2$ then $f(z)$ is not defined for $|z|>1.$

Comment: Ok...but if we require $f$ to be defined on all of $\mathbb{C}$ and that $f=\sum a_n z^n$, then we just defined an analytic function. So in particular, it's continuous everywhere and the problem is trivial

Comment: Note that the problem asks to prove that the non-tangential limit exists not that the unrestricted limit exists (the title is kind of poorly formulated) but the problem has the right conditions and then the result is correct and it is called Abel's theorem as mentioned in other comments